# Ionic 4 & RxJS 6: Ionic-native HTTP get method doesn't return data from the server

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic4, ionic-native

I am migrating from angular `HttpClient` Module to `ionic-native HTTP`, as it is impossible to access a third-party API using the standard HttpClient Module. I want to make the test of the application as easy as possible: that means, while I am adding feature to the application on my computer, I may use `HttpClient`; and while I am testing out that in a real-device, I can also do so by migrating to `ionic-native HTTP` and change a few lines of code.

The `HttpClient` works just perfectly fine in my app while I am testing it out on my computer.

My `service` written in HttpClient Module:

```
  getCaiyunForecast(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.forecastUrl)
      .pipe(map((res: any) => { return res; }), catchError(this.processHttpmsg.handleError))
  }
```

My `service` written in `ionic-native HTTP`:

```
  getCaiyunForecast(): Observable<any> {
    return of(this._http.get(this.forecastUrl, {}, {})
      .then(res => { return JSON.parse(res.data) }, res => console.log(res.data)));
  }
```

When I am subscribing to the service in my `HomePage`:

```
this.caiyunForecastService.getCaiyunForecast()
  .subscribe(res => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
      let value = this.convertService.convertSkycon(res.result.hourly.skycon[i].value)
      this.hourlyWeather.push({
        temperature: res.result.hourly.temperature[i].value.toFixed(0),
        skycon: value,
        precipitation: res.result.hourly.precipitation[i].value.toFixed(1),
        wind: {
          speed: res.result.hourly.wind[i].speed,
          direction: res.result.hourly.wind[i].direction
        },
        cloudrate: res.result.hourly.cloudrate[i].value
      });
    }
  })
```

When I do console.log in my service (`console.log(res.data)`), no value is outputted. And a "Cannot read property of hourly is undefined" is errored out; therefore, I suspect that no data is returned from the server.

Is there something I did wrong? How may I change it to make it working?

Comment: If you are using `Http` Class instead of `HttpClient`, then you need to convert the data yourself to `json` format. `{ return JSON.parse(res.json().data) }`. This is taken care by `HttpClient` automatically.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I get your point. But doesn't `JSON.parse` does the same job as `res.json()`?

Comment: @Z.Richard Do you return string from your backend?

Comment: @SurajRao But I have changed a promise to an observable using `of`. If this is not the correct way to do it, can you point out the right way to implement this change?

Comment: @AmitChigadani Probably. When I use the old `Http` but not `HttpClient` module, I have to do a `res.json()`

Comment: That is what i said in my first comment, And `JSON.parse()` is useful only when you want to convert string to an object.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Thanks for the advice. I will try adding `.json()` to the function.

Comment: @AmitChigadani It shows `.json()` does not exist on type HttpResponse.

Answer (score 0):

`of` is not used to convert promise to observable. Use `from` for rxjs 6 and `fromPromise` for rxjs 5.x

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
```

And the function

```
getCaiyunForecast(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this._http.get(this.forecastUrl, {}, {})
      .then(res => { return JSON.parse(res.data) }, res => console.log(res.data)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out.

Comment: what do you get when you log `res` in then?

Comment: I basically get nothing. No outputs in the console.

Comment: is the request getting hit? log res in the error part of then.. Also use CatchError